# Is passing data between views with pointers OK in iOS?

Tags: ios, parameter-passing

My question is more of a "is that ok" than "how to do this".
I have a simple app, based on a navigationViewController. I have a viewControllerA that is pushing another viewControllerB into the stack.What I have done is that - in viewControllerB i have a pointer of type viewControllerA, so when I am pushing it into the stack, i am saying something like that:

```
-(void)buttonPressed{
  ViewControllerB * nextView = [ViewControllerB alloc] init];
  nextView.lastView = self;
  [self.navigationViewController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES]; 
}
```

Then, in the new viewControler I am giving a value to a field in the first viewControler:

```
lastView.dataString = @"ABC";
```

So when viewControllerA closes I have changed the value of the field in the viewControllerA.

My question is: Is that OK? Can you tell me why this is not a good idea if it isn't?
I'm working with a NSString value.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically this is OK, it will work. As stated, make sure you only hold a weak reference to the previous view controller or it'll lead to a retain cycle.

This is however not really clean in terms of reusability and feature isolation.

Three other approaches you could use:

- delegation
- Key-Value Observing
- NSNotifications

Comment: Thanks, is using this a viable reason for the apple boys to turn my app off from the store?

Comment: @AlexBrest Not unless you have the aforementioned retain cycle (a.k.a. strong reference cycle), which can lead to leaks and eventually crashes. To be safe, make this is weak pointer. But Apple is not reviewing your code, so they're unaware of your decision to call this pointer back to the presenting view `lastView` rather than `delegate` and declaring it to be a pointer the the controller rather than using a protocol. They're reviewing the operation of your app, not the code.

Comment: I see. Thak you very much!

Answer (score 0):

make sure ViewControllerB is not retaining it's `lastview` property, otherwise that would be a retain cycle and the two view controllers will never be released. the correct way to pass information from a child view controller to a parent is using protocols. there are lots similar questions, for example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/568529